# Changing function name with array

Tags: javascript, function, while-loop

Could someone say how to make an array of function names that will change in while loop?

Example of what I want:

```js
var funcNames = ['function1()', 'function2()', 'function3()','function4()','function5()'];
var i = 0;
 
while( i < funcNames.length ) {
  function funcNames[i] {
    alert("hello");
  }
 
  i++;
}
```

In the example, the code doesn't work. It only shows how the code should work.

Comment: What's the [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) you try to "solve" with this construct?

Comment: This code doesn't work. In example I showed how it should work

Comment: The funcNames array doesn't make sense without more context

Comment: Third voice here for "it's not clear what you're trying to do," I'm afraid. Are you trying to *create* functions? Execute functions? Something else? Why do you have the names in an array? Etc.

Comment: Those functions don't exist. You'd have to define them first...

Comment: What should that code do? Can you add the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think about `create new dynamic function name in javascript?` like below:

```js
var funcNames = ['function1()', 'function2()', 'function3()','function4()','function5()'];
var i = 0;
var result = []; 
while( i < funcNames.length ) {
  var funcName = funcNames[i];
  var func = new Function("return function " + funcName + "{ alert('hello')}");
  result.push(func); 
  i++;
}
console.log(result);

var firstFunc = result[0]();
console.log(firstFunc()); // invoke one func here
```